# How to check against negative numbers (by user input) that are itself unsigned variables?

Tags: c

I'm trying to test against negative numbered variables that are unsigned int. Is that not possible?
It skips the `do while` loop and outputs a garbage number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned int getPositiveInteger(void);

int main(void){
  unsigned int i=getPositiveInteger();
  printf("The number is %u.\n", i);
  return 0;
}

unsigned int getPositiveInteger(void){
  int error=0;
  unsigned int n=0;
  do{
    if(error){
      printf("The number must be positive!\n");
    }
    error=0;
    printf("What's the number?\n");
    scanf("%u", &n);
    if(n<1){
      error=1;
    }
  }
  while(n<1);
  return n;
}
```

When ran:

> **What's the number?**
>
> **-1**
>
> **The number is 4294967295.**

Comment: Your variable `n` is unsigned, so even if the user inputs `-1` because you are storing it into an unsigned integer it will be interpreted as as the bit value equivalent of `-1` which will then be read as a positive integer, which means your number will be gibberish. https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-unsigned-958174

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the input number is signed, `scanf` with `%u` produces the value that results from negating the number in the `unsigned` type, so it always produces a non-negative result.

The specification of the `%u` conversion for `scanf` is in C 2018 7.21.6.2 12:

> … `u` Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value 10 for the `base` argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.

For `strtoul`, 7.22.1.4 3 says:

> … [For `base` value 10] the expected form of the subject sequence is a sequence of letters and digits representing an integer with the radix specified by `base`, optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign,…

and 7.22.1.4 5 says:

> … If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type).

Thus, for input characters “-1”, `scanf` converts “1” to an `unsigned` value of 1 and then applies the `-` operator. Arithmetic in `unsigned` wraps modulo `UINT_MAX`+1, so the mathematical negation, −1, wraps to −1+`UINT_MAX`+1, which is `UINT_MAX`.

To test whether an input is negative, you can read the individual characters and check for a “-” character. To do this, you can either accumulate characters in a temporary buffer and then use `sscanf` to process them, or you can skip white space characters until you see either a digit or a “-” (or some other character, which you would treat as an error). If it is a “-”, then report an error. If it is a digit, use `ungetc` to put it back into the input stream, then use `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

To store signed numbers you should use signed data types for variable. That's the point of signed data types.

Comment: I do not want to store signed numbers. I want to store unsigned numbers, hence why I want to check against possible signed ones; when I do that though, it skips the loop and outputs a garbage number.